# Create nested case class instance from a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I have this two case classes:

```
case class Inline_response_200(
  nodeid: Option[String],
  data: Option[List[ReadingsByEpoch_data]]
)
```

and

```
case class ReadingsByEpoch_data(
  timestamp: Option[Int],
  value: Option[String]
)
```

And I have a Cassandra table that has data like `nodeid|timestamp|value`. Basically, each `nodeid` has multiple `timestamp`-`value` pairs.

All I want to do is create instances of `Inline_response_200` with their proper List of `ReadingsByEpoch_data` so Jackson can serialize them properly to Json.

I've tried

```
val res = sc.cassandraTable[Inline_response_200]("test", "taghistory").limit(100).collect()
```

But I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to map constructor parameter data in com.wordnik.client.model.Inline_response_200 to a column of test.taghistory

Makes total sense because there is no column `data` in my Cassandra table. But then how can I create the instances correctly?

Cassandra table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.taghistory (
nodeid text,
timestamp text,
value text,
PRIMARY KEY (nodeid, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
```

**EDIT**
As per Alex Ott's suggestion:

```
val grouped = data.groupByKey.map {
  case (k, v) =>
    Inline_response_200(k.getString(0), v.map(x => ReadingsByEpoch_data(x.getInt(1), x.getString(2))).toList)
}
grouped.collect().toList
```

I'm close but not there yet. This gives me the format I expect, however its creating one instance of `Inline_response_200` per record:

```
[{"nodeid":"Tag3","data":[{"timestamp":1519411780,"value":"80.0"}]},{"nodeid":"Tag3","data":[{"timestamp":1519411776,"value":"76.0"}]}]
```

In this example I need to have one nodeid key, and an array of two timestamp-value pairs, like this:

```
[{"nodeid":"Tag3","data":[{"timestamp":1519411780,"value":"80.0"},{"timestamp":1519411776,"value":"76.0"}]}]`
```

Maybe I'm grouping the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe you could use a third case class that matches the table and then convert the dataframe to use the other two.

Comment: Inline_response_200 case class should have all the columns of the cassandra table viz., nodeid, timestamp,value. Currently, it has only 2, nodeid and data, where Ist column is of String type and 2nd column Array type.
Also, please post sample data of C* table.

Comment: Can you show your CQL schema for this table?

Comment: @pratyushsharma @AlexOtt Added CQL statement for Cassandra table. @Shaido I could do that, but that takes me back to the original question, how can I transform the dataset to create instances of the case classes? I can do `sc.cassandraTable[(String, Int, String)]("test", "taghistory")`, but don't know where to go from there..

Comment: please look into updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data like `nodeid|timestamp|value` in your DB (yes, according to schema), you can't directly map it into structure that you created. Read data from table as pair RDD:

```
val data = sc.cassandraTable[(String,String,Option[String])]("test", "taghistory")
     .select("nodeid","timestamp","value").keyBy[String]("nodeid")
```

and then transform it into structure that you need by using `groupByKey` on that pair RDD & transforming into `Inline_response_200` class that you need, like this:

```
val grouped = data.groupByKey.map{case (k,v) => Inline_response_200(k,
       v.map(x => ReadingsByEpoch_data(x._2, x._3)).toList)}
grouped.collect
```

Comment: did you use the same `cassandraTable` command as I? My command turn the table into Pair RDD by using `.keyBy[String]("nodeid")`, while your is just normal RDD

Comment: Yeah I see that, that keyBy gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple constructors with the same number of parameters not allowed.
`, so I changed it to `.keyBy("nodeid")`, but I see it messed things up.

Comment: Figured it out. Replaced `keyBy[String]("nodeid")
` with `keyBy[Tuple1[String]]("nodeid")` and `Inline_response_200(k,...` with `Inline_response_200(k._1,...`. Thanks a lot.